# Virtual MFA device on linux?

Tags: linux, security, application

There's a website which requires multi-factor authentication. Now I use google authenticator on my smartphone.

I want to make API calls (which is possible only having MFA) from my Linux therefore I need a software that will generate proper MFA codes on my box, then I'll be able to pass the codes to my script.

Is there such software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, [`oathtool`](http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/man-oathtool.html) for example. You need to provide it with the key to use obviously.

Note that using such a tool might well go against the security policies of whatever service it is you’re using, since it undermines the “multi-factor” part of the equation.